# Select all dates, all customers and the last transaction until date of the customer on a given date hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have 3 tables on Hive:
- a calendar table (with all dates on a given period)
- a customer table
- a customer's transactions list

I need to join these in order to get for a given date, all customers and their last transaction until that date. That last transaction should be null only if there are no transactions until that date (I mean, the last transaction until the current calendar record).

Calendar sample:

```
+----------+
|date      |
+----------+
|2017-06-01|
|2017-06-02|
|2017-06-03|
|2017-06-04|
|2017-06-05|
|2017-06-06|
|2017-06-07|
|2017-06-08|
|2017-06-09|
|2017-06-10|
+----------+
```

Customers sample:

```
+------------+
|customer_id |
+------------+
|11544049690 |
|15506698252 |
|67015354024 |
|43622453087 |
|509         |
|42859528435 |
|506         |
|10669246896 |
|33355892704 |
|500         |
+------------+
```

Transactions sample:

```
+------------+----------+
|customer_id |trx_date  |
+------------+----------+
|43622453087 |2018-05-30|
|509         |2017-10-04|
|509         |2018-01-09|
|509         |2017-11-07|
|509         |2018-01-30|
|506         |2017-10-04|
|506         |2017-12-21|
|506         |2017-11-07|
|506         |2017-11-07|
|500         |2017-10-04|
+------------+----------+
```

Result would be more or less like this:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
|date      |customer_id |last_trx_date |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|2017-10-04|11544049690 |              |
|2017-10-04|15506698252 |              |
|2017-10-04|67015354024 |              |
|2017-10-04|43622453087 |              |
|2017-10-04|509         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-04|42859528435 |              |
|2017-10-04|506         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-04|10669246896 |              |
|2017-10-04|33355892704 |              |
|2017-10-04|500         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-05|11544049690 |              |
|2017-10-05|15506698252 |              |
|2017-10-05|67015354024 |              |
|2017-10-05|43622453087 |              |
|2017-10-05|509         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-05|42859528435 |              |
|2017-10-05|506         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-05|10669246896 |              |
|2017-10-05|33355892704 |              |
|2017-10-05|500         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-06|11544049690 |              |
|2017-10-06|15506698252 |              |
|2017-10-06|67015354024 |              |
|2017-10-06|43622453087 |              |
|2017-10-06|509         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-06|42859528435 |              |
|2017-10-06|506         |2017-10-04    |
|2017-10-06|10669246896 |              |
|2017-10-06|33355892704 |              |
|2017-10-06|500         |2017-10-04    |
.
.
.
|2017-11-07|11544049690 |              |
|2017-11-07|15506698252 |              |
|2017-11-07|67015354024 |              |
|2017-11-07|43622453087 |              |
|2017-11-07|509         |2017-11-07    |
|2017-11-07|42859528435 |              |
|2017-11-07|506         |2017-11-07    |
|2017-11-07|10669246896 |              |
|2017-11-07|33355892704 |              |
|2017-11-07|500         |2017-10-04    |
+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Last attempt was like this one:
Here's the last attempt:

```
SELECT

    cal.date as calendar_date,
    c.customer_id,
    to_date(trx.tstamp) as trx_date,
    max(to_date(trx.tstamp)) over (
        order by trx.date, trx.customer_id rows unbounded preceding) as last_trx
    FROM
       calendartable cal
    LEFT JOIN customer t1
    LEFT JOIN transactions t2          
    ON (c.customer_id == trx.customer_id) 

    WHERE to_date(cal.date) <= current_date or cal.date is null
```

Comment: please include your attempt as well

Answer (score 0):

A cross join is needed to generate rows for every date in the calendar table per customer. Then a `left join` with aggregation would yield the desired result.

```
SELECT cal.date as calendar_date,
cst.customer_id,
max(to_date(trx.tstamp)) as last_trx
FROM calendartable cal
CROSS JOIN customer cst
LEFT JOIN transactions trx ON cst.customer_id = trx.customer_id AND trx.tstamp <= cal.dt
WHERE to_date(cal.date) <= current_date 
GROUP BY cal.date,cst.customer_id
```

Comment: The query was helpful, however I need to have the last transaction of the customer up to one given date. For example, I've got on 2016-10-09 of calendar, I've got a transaction of 2017-02-07. Last transaction date needs to either <= calendar date or null should customer haven't done any transaction until calendar date.

Comment: I was apparently able to get the desired result by changing `max(to_date(trx.tstamp)) as last_trx` to `max(if(to_date(trx.tstamp)<=cal.date,to_date(trx.tstamp),null)) as last_trx`